# Unexpected copy-construction caused by reference: what am I doing wrong?

Tags: c++, reference, c++11, copy-constructor, auto

I have some complex template code where the copy-constructor of `OPC` is being called even though I am only creating a reference to `OPC` (the actual instance is `OP_S`, which as a child class of `OPC`, should not result in a copy-construction call).

I am using gcc 4.6.1

The code is below.

```
#include <stdio.h>

class OPC
{
    public:
        OPC() { }
        OPC( const OPC& f ) {
            fprintf( stderr, "CC called!!!\n" );
        }
};

template<class T>
class SL : public T
{ };

template<class T>
class S : public SL<T>
{ };

class OP_S : public S<OPC>
{ };

class TaskFoo
{
    public:
        TaskFoo( OPC& tf ) :
            m_opc(  tf ),
            m_copc( tf )
        { }
        OPC& getOPC() { return m_opc; }

    private:
        OPC&       m_opc;
        const OPC& m_copc;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    OP_S op_s;
    TaskFoo tf( op_s );

    auto opc = tf.getOPC();  // this line results in a call to OPC's CC

    return 0;
}
```

**Answer** as noted by James McNellis below - need `auto&` instead of `auto`.

Comment: If you can post the code (or better, a simplified example), then chances are we can tell you why the copy construction is taking place.

Comment: I am trying to reproduce the same results in a sandbox atm - unfortunately, the original code is non-trivial so I can't post it here.  If I can get the sandbox to CC, I will post the code.

Comment: ok - I have reproduced the problem in the sandbox - code has been added to OP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`auto opc` declares an object, not a reference.  It is the same as if you had said `OPC opc`.

If you want `opc` to be a reference, you need `auto& opc`.

Comment: excellent - tyvm!  I was so focused on the complex hierarchy that I didn't pay attention to the auto - gotta remember that there are auto&, const auto, const auto& variations, too!

Comment: I will also grep through my code and replace most of my for( auto p : x ) with for( const auto& p : x ) or at least for( auto& p : x ), as needed.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to have `opc` as reference than it should be,

```
auto &opc = tf.getOPC();
```

In C++11, `auto` and `auto &` (luckily) have different meanings. So irrespective of `getOPC()` returning a reference `auto opc` will create an object.

Comment: ty - I just started using auto a few days ago and I did come across auto& - got blinded by the class hierarchy and didn't pay attention to the copy there.  Thanks for the reminder.